# Select a radio button with Selenium in Firefox version 27

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written Selenium tests to select a radio button. Below is the html from 'view Source' and code

**//HTML Source**

```
<b>
<font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<input type="radio" checked="" value="roundtrip" name="tripType"/>
Round Trip                  
<input type="radio" value="oneway" name="tripType"/>
One Way
</font>
</b>
```

**//Code to select radio button**

```
List<WebElement> radios = wb.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='tripType']"));
radios.get(1).click();
```

Above code did not work with Firefox ver. 27. It always used to select 1st radio button no matter what argument we send in get() function. But it worked fine in IE and Chrome. Later I upgraded Firefox to ver.31 then it started working. Curious to know the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Is it exactly the same HTML source when you open the page with Firefox 27 and with Firefox 31?

Comment: Yes its exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

try `radios[0].click()` instead of `radios.get(1).click()`